# How to minimize downtime when moving an asp.net - SQL Server site to a new host?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

We're moving & upgrading an active ASP.NET site with a sql server 2012 db to a new host company and want to minimize down time.

Our plan:

1. Recreate the db and publish the upgraded solution on the new host
2. Test the new installation

   Close the active site

   Direct the domain name pointer to the new host

During the move and testing--steps 1 & 2 above-- the existing site will remain live and users will continue to create and update records. (It could be hours of testing and fixing and we would rather not shut down for that long. Users might make hundreds of new records across dozens of tables.)

Is a full restore of the final back up of the old db the best (or only) way to update the new db with the final records from the old?

Thanks

Comment: Little note, you should change the DNS before closing the active site..(reverse step 3 & 4)

Comment: @Rob I disagree. The site needs to be down for some time so he can sync the DBs. If both site are potentially up at the same time.... different data would be in two places.

Comment: If you can put the existing site in a read-only maintenance mode, you should be able to virtually eliminate the downtime.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev He should disable the functionality, not the entire interface..

Comment: @Rob depending on his setup, read-only mode may not be feasible. Downtime of DB transfer could be only like 5-10 min. But I agree, if he can disable functionality that'd be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan sounds good, though you don't have a step for reconciling the DB. A full restore would be the easier route, but depending on the size it could increase your downtime. Your other option would be to just move the data you need, but again the "dozens" of tables could make it more complicated. If you can figure out a clean way to just reconcile new records, that'd likely be faster. Your steps would be

1. (same) Recreate the db and publish the upgraded solution on the new host
2. (same) Test new install (this could take a while... and be thorough. You said "hours" but there is no rush at this point)
3. (same) Close active site with some type of "We're moving and will be down for a few hours" message
4. (new) Now that the site is down, you reconcile the DB with either the full restore or the new records. This is what will account for your downtime (besides the DNS change delays)
5. (same) Once DB is good, update DNS

During Step 2, I would make mock runs of Step 4 so you can get a good idea of how long you can expect to be down... with both a full restore and the partial restore.

Comment: Making  mock runs of Step 4 during step 2 sounds is a good suggestion. ( I'll go with a full backup/restore since I do not know how to do partials)